# MeteorJS with spiderable - or another solution for making App crawlable?

Tags: meteor, phantomjs, iron-router

Current we are using a meteor App with the iron:router package and also the spiderable and phantomjs for making this app crawlable by google.

In our special case we have some Routes where we call Meteor methods which are running async before we render the right template into our layout.

When testing spiderable on these routes the template will never get rendered and instead our "loading" template will be the rendered template.

We are testing this with /?_escaped_fragment_=

Now we are looking for a solution to tell spiderable that the page is ready or is not ready so we can control when the page has to be rendered.

```
Router.route('/awesome-route', function(){

  // This is how it could look to tell spiderable that it has to wait
  Spiderable.pleaseWait();

  // Render the loading template until our route is ready
  this.render('loading');

  // Waiting for the response of our method
  Meteor.call('data', function(err, resp){
    this.render('awesome', {
      data : resp
    });
    // This is how it could look to tell spiderable we are ready / always be polite
    Spiderable.thanksForWaiting_WeAreReady();
  });
}, {
  name : 'awesome'
});
```

When opening now localhost:3000/awesome-route?_escaped_fragment_= we will just see the laoding template ...

The other option for us would be: Is there any alternatives for getting meteor apps crawled by google yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Since spiderable will pre-render your template using phantomjs on server, there is no need for special methods like `spiderablePleaseWaitForALittleBitMore_Please`

You can just say to your `iron:router` that template is not rendered yet. Use `onBeforeAction` hook:

```
Router.route('/awesome-route', {
  name : 'awesome',
  template: "awesome",
  loadingTemplate: "loading",
  onBeforeAction: function(){
      var next = this.next;
      Meteor.call('data', function(err, resp){
         next();
      });
  }
});
```